# Workaround/polyfill for Android 4.0.3 Stock browser z-index issues

Tags: android, z-index, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, css-position

I'm looking for a workaround or polyfill for the z-index bug described in this report:  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=31862

My markup and CSS looks basically the same as the one given in the bug report.

It'd be really great if somebody could give me a hint in the right direction on how to solve this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem, and fixed it by adding the following css to my popups:

```
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution (found here: https://coderwall.com/p/7gjkug):

`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`